# Spring Boot ElasticSearch script_lang not supported [groovy]

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, embedded

I am testing elasticsearch function in spring boot application.

spring-boot: 1.5.2.RELEASE

During Testing, I am using default embed elastic search

I got following error when I ran my test code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: script_lang not supported [groovy]
at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.getScriptEngineServiceForLang(ScriptService.java:212)
at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.compile(ScriptService.java:242)
at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.search(ScriptService.java:456)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.functionscore.script.ScriptScoreFunctionParser.parse(ScriptScoreFunctionParser.java:104)
... 20 more
```

Comment: What is your search query? What is your elasticsearch.yml? I believe you might be using a scripted query and setting the lang parameter to groovy which is by default not allowed

Comment: I am using embed elastic search

Comment: As I mentioned by default groovy is not allowed (and is deprecated starting at version 5). Not seeing your query definitely does not help, however adding `elasticsearch.script.inline=true` to your application properties might help